# What functions to use to modify ABAP DDIC objects?

Tags: abap

It is fairly easy to create ABAP program objects using the built-in statements. But what about dictionary objects? There are a lot of function groups related to DDIC, but which ones to use? Or classes perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the function modules RPY_* - they are rather complete and reliable (and RFC-enabled :-)).

Comment: Thanks, function group SIFD seems to be the one with the relevant functions.

Answer (score 0):

One class you can use is CL_REBF_DDIC_TABL. Use the static method PUT_COMPLETE. For a function module have a look at DD_CREATE_TABLE but I've never used this before.

Comment: I was unable to find this class on our CRM system. The function module looks good, but I think I prefer vwegert's suggestion, because it allows me to specify a package and transport, which is what I need. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the specific DDIC elements you want to create and have a look at the Plugins of SAPlink http://code.google.com/p/saplink/ or ZAPlink http://code.google.com/p/zaplink/.

Both support a variety of elements and show the usage of functions to create them.